# How to convert instant time to date in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have an instant time in clojure as "2016-08-03T18:45:00.000-00:00". I want to convert it to only date ("2016-08-03"). How do I do this.

My actual date is in the format "2016-08-03T18:45:00Z". I converted it to instant using (c/to-date (f/parse "2016-08-03T18:45:00Z")).How to get only date?

Thank you

Comment: You probably want to use this library:  https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time

Comment: @AlanThompson Yeah I am referring that only. But couldn't come with ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get just the date part of the date and time string:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def date-str "2016-08-03T18:45:00.000-00:00")
(first (str/split date-str #"T"))
;; => "2016-08-03"
```

Answer (score 5):

clj-time is now deprecated, new projects should use java-time:

```
(:require [java-time :as jt]))

(defn format-date
  "Format a Java instant"
   [date]
  (let [formatter         (jt/format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
        instant-with-zone (.atZone date (jt/zone-id))]
    (jt/format formatter instant-with-zone)))
```

Note that (jt/zone-id) returns the current server zone, so you must use (jt/zone-id "America/Mexico_City") if you want a static zoned date.